# Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date when I use moment.js to get current date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I used moment.js for getting current date. Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var date = moment().format("YYYY/MM/DD");
    console.log(date);
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        theme: true,
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultDate: date,
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true // allow "more" link when too many event
    });

});
```

I get current date in console along with this warning:

```
Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please refer to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info.
```

So I added ISO tag like this:

```
var date = moment().format("YYYY/MM/DD", "ddd, YYYY MM DD HH:mm:ss ZZ");
```

But I got same warning. How can I remove this warning?

Comment: Are you sure that's the line causing the warning? I think that warning comes from parsing a date string, not from formatting.

Comment: I'm editing the question and adding complete code....

Comment: What is `fullCalendar()`? Are you sure the problem isn't caused by that? Because the way you call `moment()` doesn't generate that error. What is being logged first: your `console.log()`, or the deprecation warning?

Comment: @robertklep: `console.log` is being logged first

Comment: @AjayKulkarni in that case it's fair to assume that `fullCalender()` is causing the deprecation warning.

Comment: How can I remove that warning?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not getting the warning using your code above. I was able to induce the warning using a different syntax:

```
// does not generate warning
var date1 = moment().format("YYYY/MM/DD");
console.log(date1);  

// generates warning
var date2 = moment("YYYY/MM/DD");
console.log(date2);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/zHvLm3XPkWKLSRI50UON